# SELECT from multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with a documents table

```
DocumentID   DocTitle   DocDesc
```

and a keyword table

```
KeywordID    Keyword
```

linked by a DocumentKeyword table

```
DocumentID   KeywordID
```

I have used a view to give a dataset of all the document-keyword realtionships.

```
DocumentID   DocTitle   DocDesc   Keyword
```

I am looking for a select statement that will let me search for documents by keyword.  For one keyword this is no problem I can do it.  But I would like to be able to use more than one keyword for the query, and return the documentID (once) for documents that are tagged with **all** the given keywords.

I am stuck, my biggest problem is that I can't even work out what to search for.  I realise that the view may not be necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you're expecting.  Particularly, you have a column called "keyword" for your desired output, but how do you expect multiple keywords to display in there?

Comment: will you be matching an unknown amount of keywords?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The only output I need is a list of documentIDs that match all the Keywords that have been supplied.  For example If the keywords chosen were 'IT' and 'Finance' any documentID associated with those would be required, even if they have others.  But they must have both.

Comment: @Abe: It will be an unknown amount, but if I can just get the statement for 2 I would like to try to work out how to solve the rest of it.  Best way to learn.  This just has me totally stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to specify the `keyword`, and not the `keywordid` value - use:

```
  SELECT d.documentid
    FROM DOCUMENT d
    JOIN DOCUMENTKEYWORD dk ON dk.documentid = d.documentid
    JOIN KEYWORD k ON k.keywordid = dk.keywordid
                  AND k.keyword IN ('keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3')
GROUP BY d.documentid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT k.keyword) = 3
```

The key thing is the combination of the IN and HAVING clauses - the COUNT must match the number of values supplied in the `IN` clause.

If it were `keywordid`, you could save a join and use:

```
  SELECT d.documentid
    FROM DOCUMENT d
    JOIN DOCUMENTKEYWORD dk ON dk.documentid = d.documentid
                           AND dk.keywordid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY d.documentid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dk.keywordid) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed.  I will look into sending the KeywordID over, but I think that would require an separate trip to the DB.

Comment: I looked into this.  As the view already contains the join I have modified your statement tp use the view, see my answer below. I had to make it for some other functionality anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a view to do what your doing (although your free to use one if you think it makes your code cleaner).  Using AND (preferably with an ORM to do the SQL wrangling) is the easiest.

I think this would work as well (although I don't recommend using it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT documents.DocumentID 
    FROM documents 
    WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT count(*) FROM DocumentKeyword 
           WHERE KeywordID = ANY
               (SELECT keyword.KeywordID FROM keyword 
                WHERE Keyword 
                IN ('keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3'))
           AND DocumentID = documents.DocumentID)) = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Zack, but this acts like an OR statement.  I need the document to match all the keywords not any of them, like an AND statement over different rows, if that makes sense?

Comment: Hi Zack, just to let you know.  I tried this but got the error message "Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'."  Regards

Answer (score 0):

The statement as submitted by OMG Ponies but refactored to use the view:

```
SELECT
   d.documentid 
FROM 
   v_AllDocumentKeyword d 
WHERE 
   d.keyword IN ('Keyword1','Keyword2','Keyword3')
GROUP BY 
   d.documentid 
HAVING 
   COUNT(DISTINCT d.keyword) = 3
```

Thanks